# Smooth shading creases created by spin in 3d viewport

Tags: modeling

I created the following table surface by spinning a 2d cross section in edit mode with 48 iterations. When I apply smooth shading, turn on auto smooth, and adjust normals I get a smooth vertical bezier curve, but smoothing does not happen between each of the 48 steps, even if I go all the way up to 180°. Is there a way to smooth out lines such as the ones circled in red below?

[image: Not smooth around spin]

Comment: Looks like there are faces inside there. See if any internal geometry is present (e.g run Select > All by trait > Internal Faces), then delete faces.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!